# how to make seo friendly urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo, preg-replace

hi guys iam new to 'php', i just wanted to know how to make this url into seo friendly.

iam sending two values to post.php page

`<a href='post.php?id=$pid&title=$title'>Read More....</a>`

when i click on read more....

the url to post.php must look like this `post/$title(title of that post)`

current url looks `like http://fotoshoots.be/blog/post.php?id=14&title=test`

but i want the url like `like http://fotoshoots.be/blog/post/test`

plz help me

Comment: I suggest using the following solution: http://stellarbuild.com/blog/article/making-a-blog-url-seo-friendly-with-php a totally different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, 
you need two things:
You need a "router" : PHP scripts which receive all the requests and parse it back to $_GET
https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter is a good one

the second thing is to print all URLs in the desired format e.g: /blog/page-title-here

Answer (score 0):

just use mod_rewrite. create a .htaccess file in the Directory blog with following Content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)$ post.php?title=$1 [QSA]
```

i dont know how much you know about regex, but every request that Looks like "post/your-title-here" will be replaced by post.php?title=your-title-here. please notice that this Kind of "internal Redirect" cannot find the id Parameter, post.php has to find it itseld by $title. currently the file would just allow latin characters, numbers, "_" and "-" in the request, you can Change that by changing the Content of the two square brackets according to regex rules. i hope i could help you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce, i tried it but it is not working it is giving me same output

Comment: since i dont think you changed the file Content, check the filename: it MUST HAVE the name ".htaccess" and lie in the Directory "/blog". i also found out the title-Parameter is not relevant for the request, so you could sort your articles by title and drop the id, or rewrite /post/22 to /post.php?id=22 with this code:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]*)$ post.php?id=$1 [QSA]`